# Spark Serialization workaround for 3rd party implicit vals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, sttp

I'm running a Spark job that does some Http calls along the line. I decided to use a library `Sttp` which requires an `implicit` Http backend, in my case `HttpURLConnectionBackend()`: an object apply which creates a new class instance, which is *not* serializable.

```
trait ApiUtils extends MediaTypes {

  implicit val backend: SttpBackend[Identity, Nothing, NothingT] = HttpURLConnectionBackend()

  def post = { ...
```

As a consequence, because my Spark job extends this `trait`, all methods from this `trait` inside the Spark job are not available on the executors.

As a fairly brainless workaround, I made the `val` a `def`, but what's the recommended way for sorting these things out?

The Spark job itself is a `class`, not an `object`. Reason for this is to mock/stub the mentioned Http backend inside the tests.

Comment: why not create a new sttp connection from scratch inside the post method? And therefore placing the implicit inside the post method too.

Comment: sure, making the `val` a `def` is kind of the same I suppose. I feel it's rather backwards to always recreate something which is just a value. I'm just wondering what the options are.

Comment: it is only logical, imho. Since you will be passing the object around to various executors/driverS. Each with a separate TCP/IP stack. You will definitely need to "recreate" it several times. You can try `implicit lazy val`, may be it'll work:)